# Moment generating function of f(X)

Tags: probability-theory, moment-generating-functions

I know that we can obtain the expected value of a random variable:

\begin{align}
E[X] = \int x \space  p(x) \space dx
\end{align}

and the expected value of a function of this variable:

\begin{align}
E[f(X)] = \int f(x) \space  p(x) \space dx
\end{align}

which can be used to calculate the various moments manually (i.e. $E[X^n]$).

We can also get the MGF of the random variable and use it to calculate the moments of the variable:
\begin{align}
M(t) = E(e^{tx})
\end{align}

What i'm not clear on is how we apply the MGF to a function of $X$ to generate the moments of a function of the random variable. Is this possible?

Comment: For a Borel function $f$, $f(X)$ is a random variable. And we're home

Comment: So we can write the MGF as $M(t) = E(e^{tf(x)})$?

Comment: Yes. We can write it like that

Comment: Awesome! If you want to write this as an answer i'll accept it

Comment: Nah. That wouldn't be much of an answer anyway